# Inkscape - Exclusion/Difference: remove fill but preserve stroke (size)

Tags: inkscape, path, stroke

For my background, I'm not entirely comfortable with Inkscape, but I'm not entirely new with it either.

Say I have a large object with a smaller object inside of it. I want to remove the smaller object with `Path` -> `Exclusion` (or `Difference`). If I do this, the smaller object's fill will be removed and its stroke will be preserved. However, the **stroke *size*** will be reset. Is there a way for me to preserve the stroke size when using `Exclusion`?

Neither `stroke to path` or `object to path` do what I'd like.

Let me know if I need to explain myself more.

#### EDIT

I think I just figured it out. It looks how I want it to look at least. I chose the smaller object and selected `Path` -> `Inset`. Then I chose both objects and selected `Path` -> `Exclusion`.

#### EDIT

Nevermind, I *didn't* figure it out; it doesn't work for a different set of objects.

Here's the image. I'm trying to use `Exclusion` on the mouth and teeth.
[image: golang-gopher]

Comment: Do you have different stroke weights for two objects? Can you upload your drawing?

Comment: Is that the same thing as stroke size? No, they'll all be the same stroke size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your post I understood this way.

1. I created both the paths.[image: 01]
2. Duplicated the mouth path.Ensure that duplicated mouth path is in the top Z-order.
3. Select mouth & a tooth & apply path-difference. Now your result looks like this image. Similarly repeat step 2 & 3 for another tooth.
   [image: 02]
4. Now you can move the stroked teeth downward. You can now remove the stroke & fill the mouth area. The final result after these steps.[image: 03]

Is this the result what you want ?

Comment: Wow that's some high-quality help right there. Thanks so much!